# how to get full path from binary image in odoo

Tags: python, odoo, python-imaging-library

I want to use PIL function `Image.open()`, but it only works if I pass the image path as an argument. I have to find a way to get this image path. I'm using `widget='image'` and [odoo](https://www.odoo.com) 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The images are stored in database, base64 encoded. You will have to save them to a file yourself.

```py
import tempfile
import base64
import os

from PIL import Image

from openerp import models, fields, api
from openerp.exceptions import UserError

class MyModel(models.Model):
    [...]
    image = fields.Binary()

    @api.multi
    def open_image(self):
        self.ensure_one()
        if not self.image:
            raise UserError("no image on this record")
        # decode the base64 encoded data
        data = base64.decodestring(self.image)
        # create a temporary file, and save the image
        fobj = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(delete=False)
        fname = fobj.name
        fobj.write(data)
        fobj.close()
        # open the image with PIL
        try:
            image = Image.open(fname)
            # do stuff here
        finally:
            # delete the file when done
            os.unlink(fname)
```

Comment: thx for your answer but the base64.decodestring(self.image) can't be working cause it's only take string or buffer as attributes , self.image is type binary

Comment: Did you try the code above? What error did you get? Where did you see that `self.image` is type binary? There is no such type in Python2...

Comment: THX FOR YOUR HELP  , this is the error : return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
TypeError: must be string or buffer, not bool

Comment: I updated the code to account for the lack of image.

Comment: plz i keep getting the error : UnicodeDecodeError, invalid continuation byte

Comment: I don't do interactive debugging on stackoverflow. Join #openobject on IRC (freenode), and ask there.